# Libgdx - TextureAtlas has stopped my application

Tags: java, android, libgdx, textures

I'm loading in Assets from the main game class which extends the libgdx class game. In the `create()` method of that class i'm calling `Assets.loadAtlas();` and this calls:

```
public static void loadAtlas() {
    String textureFile = "data/rubenSprite.txt";
            myTextures = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal(textureFile));

            TextureRegion[] walkRightFrames = new TextureRegion[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
            {
                walkRightFrames[i] = myTextures.findRegion("wframe" + (i + 1));
            }
            rubenWalkRight = new Animation(0.2f, walkRightFrames[0], walkRightFrames[1], 
                    walkRightFrames[2], walkRightFrames[3], walkRightFrames[4]);

            TextureRegion[] walkLeftFrames = new TextureRegion[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
            {
                walkLeftFrames[i] = new TextureRegion(walkRightFrames[i]);
                walkLeftFrames[i].flip(true,false);

            }
            rubenWalkLeft = new Animation(0.2f, walkLeftFrames[0], walkLeftFrames[1],
                    walkLeftFrames[2], walkLeftFrames[3], walkLeftFrames[4]);

            TextureRegion[] idleRightFrames = new TextureRegion[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++) 
            {
                idleRightFrames[i] = myTextures.findRegion("iframe" + (i + 1));

            }
            rubenIdleRight = new Animation(0.2f, idleRightFrames[0], idleRightFrames[1],
                    idleRightFrames[2], idleRightFrames[3]);

            TextureRegion[] idleLeftFrames = new TextureRegion[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
            {
                idleLeftFrames[i] = new TextureRegion(idleRightFrames[i]);
                idleLeftFrames[i].flip(true,false);
            }
            rubenIdleLeft = new Animation(0.2f, idleLeftFrames[0], idleLeftFrames[1], 
                    idleLeftFrames[2], idleLeftFrames[3]);

            TextureRegion[] jumpRightFrames = new TextureRegion[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                jumpRightFrames[i] = myTextures.findRegion("jframe" + (i + 1));
            }

            rubenJumpRight = new Animation(0.2f, jumpRightFrames[0], jumpRightFrames[1], 
                    jumpRightFrames[2], jumpRightFrames[3], jumpRightFrames[4]);


            TextureRegion[] jumpLeftFrames = new TextureRegion[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                jumpLeftFrames[i] = new TextureRegion(jumpRightFrames[i]);
                jumpLeftFrames[i].flip(true,false);
            }
            rubenJumpLeft = new Animation(0.2f, jumpLeftFrames[0], jumpLeftFrames[1], 
                    jumpLeftFrames[2], jumpLeftFrames[3], jumpLeftFrames[4]);   

            TextureRegion fallRight = new TextureRegion();
            fallRight = myTextures.findRegion("fall");
            rubenFallRight = new Animation(0f, fallRight);

            TextureRegion fallLeft = new TextureRegion(fallRight);      ;
            fallLeft.flip(true,false);
            rubenFallLeft = new Animation(0f, fallLeft);
    }
```

From the tutorials I've looked at, it seems correct to me. I've given the player states and drawn the animations within them inside the mainRenderer depending on the state the player is in. This code seems fine also:

```
private void renderRuben () {
        TextureRegion keyFrame;
        switch (world.ruben.getState()) {
        case Ruben.RUBEN_STATE_HIT:
            keyFrame = Assets.bobHit;
            break;
        case Ruben.RUBEN_STATE_WALKING: 
            if (Ruben.facingRight == true) 
            {
                keyFrame = Assets.rubenWalkRight.getKeyFrame(world.ruben.getStateTime(), Animation.ANIMATION_NONLOOPING);
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                keyFrame = Assets.rubenWalkLeft.getKeyFrame(world.ruben.getStateTime(), Animation.ANIMATION_NONLOOPING);
                break;
            }
        case Ruben.RUBEN_STATE_FALL:
            if (Ruben.facingRight == true) {
                keyFrame = Assets.rubenFallRight.getKeyFrame(world.ruben.getStateTime(), Animation.ANIMATION_NONLOOPING);
                break;
                                           }
            else {
                keyFrame = Assets.rubenFallLeft.getKeyFrame(world.ruben.getStateTime(), Animation.ANIMATION_NONLOOPING);
                break;
                 }
        case Ruben.RUBEN_STATE_JUMP:  
            if (Ruben.facingRight == true) {
                keyFrame = Assets.rubenJumpRight.getKeyFrame(world.ruben.getStateTime(), Animation.ANIMATION_NONLOOPING);
                break;
                                           }
            else {
                keyFrame = Assets.rubenJumpRight.getKeyFrame(world.ruben.getStateTime(), Animation.ANIMATION_NONLOOPING);
                break;
                 }
        case Ruben.RUBEN_STATE_IDLE:
        default:
            if (Ruben.facingRight == true) {
            keyFrame = Assets.rubenIdleRight.getKeyFrame(world.ruben.getStateTime(), Animation.ANIMATION_LOOPING);
            }
            else {
            keyFrame = Assets.rubenIdleRight.getKeyFrame(world.ruben.getStateTime(), Animation.ANIMATION_LOOPING);
            }
    }


        float side = world.ruben.getVelocity().x < 0 ? -1 : 1;
        if (side < 0)
            batch.draw(keyFrame, world.ruben.position.x + 0.5f, world.ruben.position.y - 0.5f, side * Ruben.RUBEN_WIDTH, Ruben.RUBEN_HEIGHT);
        else
            batch.draw(keyFrame, world.ruben.position.x - 0.5f, world.ruben.position.y - 0.5f, side * Ruben.RUBEN_WIDTH, Ruben.RUBEN_HEIGHT);
    }
```

I packed the Atlases using TexturePacker GUI and saved the png and txt file into /assets/data folder.

The overall project has no errors, it just says 'application not responding' when it opens up in the emulator. What am i doing wrong?

Create Method for game class:

```
public class GameView extends Game {
    // used by all screens
    public SpriteBatch batcher;
    @Override
    public void create () {
        batcher = new SpriteBatch();
        Settings.load();
        Assets.loadAtlas();
        setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `create` method? I suggest putting break-points throughout your `create` method as well as the methods it calls and step through in the debugger to find out where the ANR is coming from. BTW, static references to Textures or TextureAtlases will cause big problems in libgdx on Android (although not the one you described).

Comment: Okay i've posted the create method for the game class that calls the Assets class (edited), I'll put some breakpoints and change static variables, i'll post my command log when complete

Comment: misread your comment, i won't touch the static variables in that case

Comment: Overall it was something to do with the Emulator not the application, The emulator wasn't compatible with Open GL ES 2.0, So I downloaded GenyMotion and now it works fine. Thankyou for the effort though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall it was something to do with the Emulator not the application, The emulator wasn't compatible with Open GL ES 2.0, So I downloaded GenyMotion and now it works fine.

http://www.genymobile.com/en/